# Binary Tree With Exercise in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I have been given an assignment at my university where we have to solve the following exercise:

In this problem we consider, given a positive integer n, additive expressions of the form

`n = 1 ± 2 ± 3 ± 4 ± ... ± n − 2 ± n − 1 ± n`

For example, for n = 5, the following two expressions are the only valid ones of that form:

- `5 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 − 5`
- `5 = 1 − 2 − 3 + 4 + 5`

Write a program that accepts on its input an integer n (where 0 < n < 30) and outputs the number of expressions of the above form that evaluate to n.

Now I know that I should be looking to make a binary tree with loops and recursion. But we have not done much with pointers yet and I do not really know where to start or how to build up a binary tree like this. Maybe there is a trick and the program does not have to be so complicated but I have not found a shortcut. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Maybe there is a trick" - There is no "trick. It's going to take some effort. [How do you get to Carnegie Hall?](https://www.carnegiehall.org/BlogPost.aspx?id=4295022505). If you're asking whether this problem could be solved in different ways, certainly. Building a tree is certainly among them. Backtracking would be another. Chances are if the subject being studied is trees and recursion (or backtracking), they probably want you to solve it that way.

Comment: Have you actually been told to solve this with a binary tree? Or can you solve it any way you want?

Comment: We have only been told to use recursion that is all. But the previous exercises we had were the maximum difficulty of using loops. We have been taught what pointers are but it would be a huge jump if we actually had to create something like this. That is why I taught there there might be another solution.

Comment: There is a small trick: Half of the numbers have zero representations.

Comment: Please affirm that starting with -1 is _not_ allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use recursion there is no need to build a binary tree. The recursive calls will do that for you, under the hood so to speak.

Below is a raw O(2^n) solution.

```
// Calculate the number of ways to get a sum of -value given the numbers ±1 to ±n.
int func(int value, int level) {
  if (level == 0) {
    // Base case
    return (value == 0);
  }
  // Recursive step. 
  return func(value + level, level - 1) + func(value - level, level - 1);
}

int main(void) {
   int level;
   for (level = 0; level < 10; level++) {
       printf("n=%d, reult=%d\n", func(-level, level));
   }
}
```

Comment: It is rather O(2^n). There are 2^n ways to assign `+` and `-`, and you test them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
void printSolution(int* arr, int n) {
    printf("1");
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        if(arr[i] == -1) // '-' sign
        {
            printf(" - ");
        } 
        else { // if arr[i] == 1, then '+' sign
            printf(" + ");
        }
        printf("%d", i + 2);
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", n);
}

int numberofExpressionHelper(int indx, int *arr, int n, int sum) {
    // base case; we end up putting all (n - 1) signs between numbers
    // Now if the sum is equal to n, we get one solution
    if(indx == n - 1) {
        if(sum == n) {
            printSolution(arr, n);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int ret;
    ret = 0;
    // putting '+' in between 
    arr[indx] = 1; // +
    int right_operand;
    right_operand = indx + 2;
    // As we put '+', we add right operand with sum for next call
    ret += numberofExpressionHelper(indx + 1, arr, n, sum + right_operand);

    // putting '-' in between
    arr[indx] = -1; // -
    // As we put '-', we subtract right operand from sum for next call
    ret += numberofExpressionHelper(indx + 1, arr, n, sum - right_operand);

    return ret;
}

void numberofExpression(int n) {
    if(n <= 0) return; // assuming given input will be greater than 0

    // arr[i] will contain the sign(+ or -) between number i + 1 and i + 2
    // e.g. arr[0] will contain the sign between 1 and 2
    // We will keep 1 for '+' and -1 for '-' in the arr
    // e.g. 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 5 = 5
    // the corresponding arr will be [1, 1, 1, -1]
    // e.g. 1 - 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 = 5
    // arr = [-1, -1, 1, 1]
    int arr[n];

    // start sum with 1 as first element will be obviously 1
    int result;
    result = numberofExpressionHelper(0, arr, n, 1);
    printf("Total number of expressions: %d\n", result);
}
```

Example:

```
numberofExpression(5);
```

output:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 5 = 5
1 - 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 = 5
Total number of expressions: 2
```

As you said, you know about recursion. Now debug this program with your IDE and/or try to understand the program flow with pen and paper, I hope you will get the idea. Here `arr` is passed as pointer to array which saves us from copying the whole array as parameter during function call.

The idea is not about building the actual binary tree. Rather to design an recursion tree which emits two branches(one for '+' and one for '-') in every level until reaching a valid/invalid solution(leaf).

Comment: Hm. I missed the sign of 1 being stuck at +.